# Are the GNU Netcat commands the same as netcat-openbsd or netcat-traditional?

Tags: linux, netcat

I can't find the list of commands for GNU Netcat.

But they say on their [official website](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) the following:

> Goals of this project are full compatibility with the original nc 1.10
>   that is widely used, and portability.

So this means that their commands are the same as nc 1.10, right? But is nc 1.10 considered to be netcat-openbsd or netcat-traditional?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

nc 1.10 is [`netcat-traditional`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/netcat), which was released by Avian Research and last updated “officially” in 1996. It’s been extensively patched since then, and GNU Netcat was started as a development branch of Avian Netcat.

(This is based on [information contained in the Debian package](https://sources.debian.net/src/netcat/1.10-41.1/debian/copyright/).)

GNU Netcat doesn’t appear to have been developed much; OpenBSD Netcat is the more interesting alternative nowadays.